# How to remove a notification from the status bar when the user press on it to open a activity?

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that receives push notifications from C2DM server with a BroadcastReceiver. When the user press on the notification on the status bar, a random activity from my app is opened.

I need that when the user press on the notification, the notification get's removed from the status bar. ¿how can i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may try this `notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`

Answer (score 0):

when you launch the activity call [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29)